# Auto Scroll Nested Recycler view , during drag and drop

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nestedrecyclerview

I wrote this function to handle scrolling for my nested VERTICAL recycler views. ( both of them vertical ! I have disabled nestedScrolling in the child recycler Views )

```
    val mgr: LinearLayoutManager = vList.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager
    val iFirst: Int = mgr.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
    val iLast: Int = mgr.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()

    // Auto-Scroll:
    if (mgr.findViewByPosition(iFirst) === viewHoveredOver) toScroll.scrollBy(0,-35)
    else if (mgr.findViewByPosition(iLast) === viewHoveredOver) toScroll.scrollBy(0,35)
}
```

But... turns out : The child recycler view always returns the LAST and FIRST item position in findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition/findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition , instead of the actual visible items !

that is : if the item count is 10 & visible items is 4 , findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition would still return 9 , instead of 3